Parameter Order Evaluation for Variable-sized Multidimensional Arrays
When declaring functions in C to accept a parameter for a multi-dimensional array (2D in this case), I struggle to understand how a declaration like this:
type function_name(int ROW, int COLUMN, type array[ROW][COLUMN]) {
    // Function body
}

would compile successfully and accept row and column dimensions from the former two parameters. Is there a specific order of evaluation for parameters declared this way?
Considering the stack level, before the function is called, these parameters would be pushed in reverse order—starting with array, then COLUMN, and finally ROW. But how would the array have knowledge of the latter two parameters beforehand? Would it be correct to say:

This arrangement is valid because arrays with non-constant dimensions can use parameters evaluated earlier in the function declaration.

Is there something I'm misunderstanding here?

Can you just pass an array by passing the address to the first item? So pass a pointer? The dimension are not needed. As you pass them as additional arguments. So, int x, int y, int *parray. These are my thoughts. I don’t compile with C any more.

Parameters are not necessarily pushed on a stack. On x86_64 architecture, for example, all of the parameters will be in the registers. Nevertheless, array pointer will be just a pointer. What will be done later depends on how VLA actually works.

The array is not "pushed to the stack". Nor passed to the function . Only a pointer to the first array element is passed to the function so the actual array sizee doesn't matter.

I suspect that because of the special way in which array parameters are handled in C, the two size indicators are irrelevant.

the size indicator are relevant. int A[size] is a different type than int *A. the compiler does some checks with the types involved. but the stack evaluation, i think, is not involved here. it is my opinion, i will wait for someone to quote standard.

The parameter that is declared as an array of arrays is adjusted to be a pointer to an array. When called, all the parameters are initialized to the values of the arguments. This does not require evaluating the array dimensions. The C 2018 standard does not specify whether the first array dimension, which has been removed by adjustment, is evaluated or not. Some compilers have evaluated it while others have not. To determine the type of the pointer for the duration of the function execution, the second dimension is evaluated. This does not present any problem with initializing parameters.

how would the array have knowledge of the latter two parameters beforehand? so just compute ROW and COLUMN without pushing to stack.

C 2024 is silent about sequencing of parameter initialization and evaluation of dimensions of variably modified parameters. A paragraph in 6.9.2 describes them in informal English in an order that is logically inconsistent: “On entry to the function, the size expressions of each variably modified parameter and typeof operators used in declarations of parameters are evaluated and the value of each argument expression is converted to the type of the corresponding parameter as if by assignment.”

There is an ordering enforced by scope: The scope of each parameter begins after its declarator ends, so array sizes can only use parameters declared earlier. This does not impose any sequencing on evaluation.

(I cannot easily write these comments up as an answer since I am on a tour bus in Albania. I will leave that to others for now.)

Inside the function, the compiler treats the arg named array as a pointer to a one-dimensional array of type that has length COLUMN. However, the only information needed for the compiler to generate the code that reflects the function signature itself, is that array is a pointer. That is, at the machine level, the argument is simply an unsigned integer (machine binary word) that is the size of a pointer (for the particular hardware architecture). So, for the compiler to generate the lower-level code for the array as an arg to the function, specific values of ROW and COLUMN aren't needed.
As mentioned, when array is used inside the function, the compiler treats array as a pointer to a one-dimensional array of type that has length COLUMN (and the value of ROW isn't strictly needed by the compiler, see below).
E.g. If array[2][1] is accessed inside the function, the compiler can generate code that effectively uses a memory offset from the value of array that is equivalent to
offset = n * sizeof(type) where
n = 2 x COLUMN + 1
(2 is the row subscript, and 1 is the column subscript)
If, for example, type is char and ROW is 4 and COLUMN is 10, then inside the function, array is treated as a pointer to an array of 10 chars. So access of array[2][1] uses:
offset = n * sizeof(type) =>
offset = (2 * COLUMN + 1) * sizeof(char) =>
offset = (2 * 10 + 1) * sizeof(char) =>
offset = 21 * sizeof(char) = 21
So for access of array[2][1] with ROW = 4 and COLUMN = 10, the compiler uses an offset of 21 elements from the value of array arg, whereby the size of each element is sizeof(type). In the example here, type is char so sizeof(type) is 1. (Again, note that ROW isn't strictly needed by the compiler for the offset [i.e. index] determination).
(Note that sizeof terminology is used merely for descriptive purposes. Also, your example code raises bounds checking concerns.)


Considering the stack level, before the function is called, these
parameters would be pushed in reverse order—starting with array, then
COLUMN, and finally ROW.

Your considerations are wrong. C language does not know anything about the stack and how parameters are passed is the part of ABI.

But how would the array have knowledge of the latter two parameters
beforehand?

You do not pass array, you only pass the reference to the first element of the array. Nothing else.
When you actually access this array in the function body, the compiler will generate the code taking into account the passed parameters.

This arrangement is valid because arrays with non-constant dimensions
can use parameters evaluated earlier in the function declaration.

No, it is incorrect. You need to pass the sizes first to prevent syntax error (unknown identifier - in C you always need to declare the identifier first before using it). The dimensions will be used when you access the array in the function body. Nothing is "calculated" beforehand.

C has no multidimensional arrays. It has “array of type”, and the type can itself be an array which then looks like a multidimensional array.
So if you write int a[10][20] it’s clearly an array with 20 elements, and each array element consists of ten ints.
If you let n = 3, m = 5, and access a[n][m], then you access the third array of ten ints, and the fifth of ten elements in that array. Which is the 35th int.
